# Auto-generated .sty file call unexisting packages

Tags: packages

I just updated MikTeX, which I didn't do in years. From now on, several packages return an error when call. The auto-generated .sty file try to call packages now included as tools (calc, verbatim...).

How can I solve it? Thanks

Comment: Show a small document that errors and show the *first* error exactly as it is written in the log-file.

Comment: note for some years the bundle has been known as latex-tools (not just tools) for ctan and so tex distribution updates